# multiprocessing.pool gets stuck while doing parallel calculation

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

(This is using python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.02)

Problem Solved:

There's something wrong in my heavy_calculation function when j=2, hence the code can't give the answer. It's not a problem with multiprocessing.

However, although the code can work properly now, it reports an error when I use multiprocessing.dummy instead of multiprocessing. The error is the same as I wrote in Addition part. It's not a fatal error, I think, otherwise the code can't work at all. Can I ignore it?

Addition:

I use multiprocessing.dummy to debug.

When PROCESSES > 1 (e.g. PROCESSES = 2), the code exits as soon as pool.map begins, with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binfit1.py", line 81, in <module>
    pool.map(multifit_star,parm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Question:

I'd like to do some heavy calculation simultaneously and I use multiprocessing package. However, multiprocessing.Pool will get stuck while calculating. The simplified version of my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
def f(i,j):
    result = heavy_calculation(i,j)  
    result_star = np.array([result])
    # save the result in a certain file
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        temp = np.load('result.npy')
        temp = np.append(temp,result_star,axis=0)
    except:
        temp = result_star
    print temp
    np.save('result.npy',temp)
    lock.release()
def f_star(x):
    return f(*x)
if __name__=='__main__':
    k = 3
    PROCESSES = 4  #I have 8 cores in my computer
    lock = mp.Lock()
    parm = []
    for m in range(0,k):
        for n in range(0,k):
            parm.append([m,n])
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=PROCESSES)
    pool.map(f_star,parm)            
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    final_result = np.load('result.npy')
    print final_result
```

When I run this code on terminal, it works well for several processes but then gets stuck somewhere in pool.map(f_star,parm). For example, if I set k=3, which means the last temp that printed by f(i,j) should have a length of 3*3=9, the code will stall at a point when the length of temp is only 6. The 6 results it gives are right, yet it never gives the other 3.

As the execution never finishes, I have to restart the terminal. What's the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Sincerely,

Schur

Comment: `parm` contains an empty list as first element (`parm = [[]]`) so there should be an exception in a worker process.

Comment: For debugging I often try `import mutliprocessing.dummy as mp` (using threads) instead of `import multiprocessing as mp` - If your `heavy_calculation` function spends most of its time in numpy then there might even be comparable performance to real multiprocessing.

Comment: What is `iter`? And you'd better use another variable name instead of this keyword.

Comment: Try initializing `parm` to `[]`. Every other element is a two-element list of `[m, n]`, except for the first one now that is an empty list. As @janbrohl said, function `f` expects two arguments, not 0 arguments.

Comment: @janbrohl Thanks. That is a typing mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: @chapelo It's also a typing bug while simplifying the code...It's the integer k. I've corrected. Thanks.

Comment: You still have some `multiprocessing` instead of `mp` as you imported it. But, Does it work now?

Comment: @janbrohl I use multiprocessing.dummy as you said and I've added the information it gave in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @chapelo I've corrected it. However it still fails to work. I've added more information in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code could run as it is listed without an exception. You aren't passing lock in as one of the parameters to f_star/f so there should be an exception thrown about lock not being defined.